# Can't GROUP BY correctly (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an SQL query that currently displays all the people in table `HOTEL` that booked a hotel between $260 and $350. I'm using ORACLE

```
SELECT guest.guest_name "GUEST NAME", 
       Count(guest.guest_no), 
       guest.guest_no   "GUEST           NUMBER", 
       room.r_price     "ROOM PRICE" 
FROM   room, 
       guest, 
       booking 
WHERE  r_price >= 260 
       AND r_price <= 350 
       AND guest.guest_no = booking.guest_no 
GROUP  BY guest.guest_no, 
       guest.guest_name, 
       room.room_price 
ORDER  BY guest.guest_name;
```

I thought that I could group by just GUEST.GUEST_NAME (so it puts all of the count under the one name rather than doubling up on the guest names).

EDIT: The current results of the query look like this:

```
    GUEST NAME    COUNT   GUEST_NO R_PRICE
    Jenny Freeman   2   G003    260
    Jenny Freeman   2   G003    295
    Jenny Freeman   2   G003    310
    Martin Ferguson 3   G006    260
    Martin Ferguson 3   G006    295
    Martin Ferguson 3   G006    310
    Paul Happy  3   G002    260
    Paul Happy  3   G002    295
    Paul Happy  3   G002    310
    Steve Kirkwood  3   G005    260
    Steve Kirkwood  3   G005    295
    Steve Kirkwood  3   G005    310
    Tina Duncan 2   G001    260
    Tina Duncan 2   G001    295
    Tina Duncan 2   G001    310
    Vanessa Horton  1   G007    260
    Vanessa Horton  1   G007    295
    Vanessa Horton  1   G007    310
```

But I'm expecting something like this:

```
    GUEST NAME    COUNT   GUEST_NO R_PRICE
    Jenny Freeman   6   G003    260
    Martin Ferguson 9   G006    310
    Paul Happy  9   G002    310
    Steve Kirkwood  9   G005    260
    Tina Duncan 6   G001    310
    Vanessa Horton  3   G007    260
```

Comment: you don't seem to have a link between booking and room in your sql.

Comment: What output do you want? Please tell us what you want the query to do! Then we can tell you if the query you have should do that, is very close to doing what you want, or if you are completely on the wrong track.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Try taking guest_no and room_price out of the group by and guest_no out of the select fields.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm a massive noob haha.. The output I want is the numbers and names of guests who booked rooms in the price range
between 230 and 350 dollars. Also how many times they booked such rooms.

Comment: so may be you don't need a room_price in your output?

Comment: @danboy what RDBMS are you using? MySQL, sql server, oracle?

Comment: you need to decide, do you want max(R_PRICE) or min(R_PRICE) in output. For Vanessa Horton you indicated min (260) and for Paul Happy you indicated max (310)

Comment: Sorry i didn't specify, i'm using ORACLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you just have to change in group by statement rest looks OK to me. Just don't include Room price in Group By statement, i think that is creating problem for you if i am getting your question right...

```
 GROUP BY GUEST.GUEST_NO,
          GUEST.GUEST_NAME
```

and

```
 MAX(R_PRICE)
```

Comment: AHHH this seemed to do it! I had to get rid of room.r_price in the select AND group by statements. I thought that since i was specifying between two values in room.r_price, i had to have it in select but it can read it fine without it being there. Thanks :)

what was the MAX(R_PRICE) for?

Comment: except now when i have what you/I wrote all of my results are tripled, hmmm

Comment: just in case u want to get the max of the r_price.

Comment: Well if you group by r_price it will group using that case also which is not single entry i guess. So it will replicate the above results also as it is with the change in R_price only..That is the reason u were facing issues..Anyways good luck with that..

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to join ROOM with BOOKING by ROOM_NO (or other field)?
I've removed ROOM PRICE from group by, query now will will return unique guests and number of rooms they booked with price in given range, and max price for each guest.

```
SELECT
    GUEST.GUEST_NAME "GUEST NAME",
    GUEST.GUEST_NO "GUEST NUMBER",
    COUNT(*) "CNT",
    MAX(R.R_PRICE) "ROOM PRICE"
FROM BOOKING B
    inner join ROOM R on R.ROOM_NO = B.ROOM_NO
    inner join GUEST G on G.GUEST_NO  = B.GUEST_NO
WHERE R.R_PRICE>=260 and R.R_PRICE<=350
GROUP BY G.GUEST_NO, G.GUEST_NAME
ORDER BY G.GUEST_NAME;
```

Comment: @danboy, I've added ";" at the end. You didn't specify that you have oracle database.

Comment: Yeah i noticed it was missing but it still has the same error. Thanks for your help so far, I should have specified oracle before

Answer (score -2):

You can try the below sql query:

```
SELECT GUEST.GUEST_NAME "GUEST NAME", COUNT(GUEST.GUEST_NO), GUEST.GUEST_NO "GUEST NUMBER", ROOM.R_PRICE "ROOM PRICE"
FROM ROOM, GUEST,BOOKING
WHERE ROOM.R_PRICE>=260
AND ROOM.R_PRICE<=350
AND GUEST.GUEST_NO = BOOKING.GUEST_NO
GROUP BY GUEST.GUEST_NAME
ORDER BY GUEST.GUEST_NAME;
```

Comment: See when i try this is says that "not a GROUP BY expression" which I understand to mean (after researching it) that I need to include all the select statements in the group by, i'm not sure why though.

Comment: Sorry i changed the query to GROUP BY GUEST.GUEST_NAME

This will give you unique guest names

Comment: it will not work, you need to add aggregate over GUEST_NO AND R_PRICE or add it into group by clause